# validar formulario con php por medio de post sin que se borre el valor de los campos

Tags: php, html

> Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, tengo el siguiente formulario (del cual omiti gran parte del codigo por que son muchos campos). Donde hago una validacion con php, en un alert me muestra los campos que estan vacios, resetea los valores de los campos cuando se envia el post y no quiero ya que si faltan valores regresa al formulario y campos estan en blanco, entonces tengo que agregar a cada campos el valor enviado por post de la siguiente forma.

```
value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){ echo $_POST['nombre'];} ?>"
```

Quedando asi.

```
<input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){ echo $_POST['nombre'];} ?>" placeholder="Escribe el Nombre"  >
```

Quiero que cuando se envien los datos para valudacion no se borren por que

```html
include 'controlador.php';

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" style="background:#2E59D9 !important; color: #ffffff !important;">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="background:#2E59D9 !important; color: #ffffff !important;">
DATOS DEL PACIENTE
</button>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="insertPaciente" id="insertPaciente">
          <div class="row  card-body" style="background:#2E59D9 !important; color: #ffffff !important;">

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label>Elije el tipo de registro</label></br>
              <?php 
$tipoAtn="";
if(isset($_POST['tipoAtn'])){
$tipoAtn=$_POST['tipoAtn'];
}
$idInst="";
if(isset($_POST['idInst'])){
$idInst=$_POST['idInst'];
} 
?>
              <select class="form-control texto" name="tipoAtn" id="tipoAtn" value="" onchange="tipoAtnOnchange(this);">
                <option hidden selected value="">Elije una opción</option>
                <option class="form-control" <?php if($tipoAtn=="Ingreso" ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="Ingreso">Ingreso</option>
                <option class="form-control" <?php if($tipoAtn=="Reingreso" ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="Reingreso">Reingreso</option>
                <option class="form-control" <?php if($tipoAtn=="Defunción en domicilio" ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="Defunción en domicilio">Defunción en domicilio</option>
                <option class="form-control" <?php if($tipoAtn=="Defunción en otro estado" ){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="Defunción en otro estado">Defunción en otro estado</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="defoe" style="display:none">
              <label>Unidad de atención:</label></br>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="idUnidadOTRO" id="idUnidadOTRO" value="">
            </div>

            <?php if ( $_SESSION['permiso']== 2 || $_SESSION['permiso']== 1) {?>
            <div class="form-group row col-md-6" id="defoeN" style="display:none">
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label>Institución:</label><br/>
                <select class="form-control texto" name="idInst" id="idInst">
                  <option hidden selected value="">Selecciona la institución</option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="IMS" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="IMS">IMSS </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="IMO" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="IMO">IMSS-BIENESTAR </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="IST" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="IST">ISSSTE </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="CIJ" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="CIJ">Centro de Integraciín Juvenil </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="CRO" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="CRO">Cruz Roja Mexicana </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="PMX" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="PMX">PEMEX </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="SDN" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="SDN">SEDENA </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="SME" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="SME">Centro de Atención Integral </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="SMP" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="SMP">SM Privado </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="SSA" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="SSA">SSA </option>
                  <option <?php if($idInst=="SCT" ){ echo 'selected' ;}?> value="SCT">Unidad de protec. y med. preventiva </option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                <label>Unidad de atención:</label></br>
                <select class="form-control texto" name="idUnidad" id="idUnidad">
                  <option hidden selected value="">Selecciona la unidad</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php //}else{?>
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Nombre:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){ echo $_POST['nombre'];} ?>" placeholder="Escribe el Nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="apellidos">Apellido paterno:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="apPaterno" id="apPaterno" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['apPaterno'])){ echo $_POST['apPaterno'];} ?>" placeholder="Escribe el apellido paterno">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="apellidos">Apellido materno:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="apMaterno" id="apMaterno" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['apMaterno'])){ echo $_POST['apMaterno'];} ?>" placeholder="Escribe el apellido materno">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">CURP:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="curp" id="curp" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['curp'])){ echo $_POST['curp'];} ?>" placeholder="Escribe la CURP">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Número de expediente:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="nExp" id="nExp" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nExp'])){ echo $_POST['nExp'];} ?>" placeholder="Número de expediente">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Estado de residencia:</label>
              <option hidden selected value="">Selecciona el estado</option>
              <select class="form-control texto" name="estadoR" id="estadoR" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['estadoR'])){ echo $_POST['estadoR'];} ?>" placeholder="">
                <option selected hidden disabled value="">Selecciona el estado</option>
                <?php
      foreach ($estado as $row):
      ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row['idEstado']?>">
                    <?php echo $row['estado']; ?>
                  </option>
                  <?php
      endforeach;
      ?>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Municipio de residencia actual:</label></br>
              <select class="form-control texto" name="municipioR" id="municipioR" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['municipioR'])){ echo $_POST['municipioR'];} ?>" placeholder="Escribe el Nombre" onChange="muniROnChange(this);">

              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Domicilio:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="domicilio" id="domicilio" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['domicilio'])){ echo $_POST['domicilio'];} ?>" placeholder="Domicilio">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Telefono:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['telefono'])){ echo $_POST['telefono'];} ?>" placeholder="Número de telefono">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Número interno:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="nInterno" id="nInterno" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nInterno'])){ echo $_POST['nInterno'];} ?>" placeholder="Número interno">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Número de cama:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="nCama" id="nCama" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nCama'])){ echo $_POST['nCama'];} ?>" placeholder="Número interno">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="date" name="fechaNac" id="fechaNac" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fechaNac'])){ echo $_POST['fechaNac'];} ?>" placeholder="día/mes/año" onChange="calcularEdad(this);">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Edad:</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="input" name="edad" id="edad" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['edad'])){ echo $_POST['edad'];} ?>" placeholder="Edad del paciente">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="genero">Sexo:</label><br>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" style="background:#d7f4ec !important; color: #2E59D9 !important;">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button style="" class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
DATOS DE LA ATENCIÓN
</button>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample" style="/*background:#FF5AC8 !important; color: #ffffff !important;">

              <div class="row card-body">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                  <label>Fecha de Ingreso:</label>
                  <input class="form-control fecha" type="date" name="Fingreso" id="Fingreso" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['edad'])){ echo $_POST['edad'];} ?>" onChange="DiasEstancia(this);">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                  <label>Servicio: </label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="servicio" id="servicio">
                    <option class="form-control" hidden selected value="" value="">Elige una opción</option>
                    <option class="form-control">Fuera de UCI con ventilador</option>
                    <option class="form-control">Fuera de UCI sin ventilador</option>
                    <option class="form-control">Dentro de UCI con ventilador</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label>¿Es una paciente embarazada o puerperio?:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="embarzoPuer" id="embarzoPuer">
                    <option class="form-control" hidden selected value="" value="">Elige una opción</option>
                    <option class="form-control" value="">No aplica</option>
                    <option class="form-control" value="Emb 1er trimestre">Emb 1er trimestre</option>
                    <option class="form-control" value="Emb 2do trimestre">Emb 2do trimestre</option>
                    <option class="form-control" value="Emb 3er trimestre">Emb 3er trimestre</option>
                    <option class="form-control" value="Puerperio">Puerperio</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row col-md-12" style="margin-left: 1%;">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <h5>Comorbilidades</h5>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">NOTA: Para agregar mas de una comorbilidad utilice el caracter coma ","</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comor[]" id="DM" value="Diabetes Mellitus" /> Diabetes Mellitus<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comor[]" id="HTA" value="Hipertensión Arterial" /> Hipertensión Arterial<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comor[]" id="SP" value="Sobrepeso-Obesidad" /> Sobrepeso-Obesidad<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comor[]" id="IRC" value="Insuficiencia Renal Crónica" /> Insuficiencia Renal Crónica<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comor[]" id="EPOC" value="EPOC-ASMA" /> EPOC-ASMA<br /> Otra
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="otroC" name="comor[]" value="" placeholder="Otras comorbilidades" onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode ==44) || (event.charCode ==32))"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <textarea class="form-control" type="input" name="comorbilidades" id="comorbilidades" rows="5" cols="50" onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode ==44) || (event.charCode ==32))"></textarea>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                      <label>Diagnosticos al ingreso:</label>
                      <input class="form-control fecha" type="input" name="dxIngreso" id="dxIngreso" value="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                      <label>Condición al ingreso de protocolo de estudio:</label>
                      <select class="form-control" name="condfReporte" id="condfReporte">
                        <option class="form-control" hidden selected value="" value="">Elige una opción</option>
                        <option class="form-control" value="Ambulatorio (Caso leve)">Ambulatorio (Caso leve)</option>
                        <option class="form-control" value="Estable">Estable</option>
                        <option class="form-control" value="Grave">Grave</option>
                        <option class="form-control" value="Crítico (Intubado)">Crítico (Intubado)</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-footer">

                    <input type="hidden" name="guardarPaciente" value="si" />
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrar" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```

> archivo controlador.php

```html
<?php 

 if(isset($_POST['guardarPaciente']))
  {  if ( $_POST["nombre"] !="" && $_POST["apPaterno"] !="" && $_POST["apMaterno"] !="" && $_POST["edad"] !="" && $_POST["genero"] !="" && $_POST["fechaNac"] !="" && $_POST["servicio"] !="" && $_POST["Fingreso"] !="" &&  $_POST["condfReporte"] !="" && $_POST["tipoAtn"] !="") 
    {
        "GUARDA LO DATOS"
  }else{
$tipoAtn='';
$nombre='';
$apPaterno='';
$apMaterno='';
$edad='';
$genero='';
$fechaNac='';
$servicio='';
$dxIngreso='';
$Fingreso='';
$condfReporte='';

$mensaje="";
 if( $_POST["tipoAtn"] == ""){  $tipoAtn= "Tipo de registro"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$tipoAtn; }
 if( $_POST["nombre"] == ""){  $nombre= "Nombre"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$nombre; } 
 if( $_POST["apPaterno"] == ""){ $apPaterno= "Apellido paterno"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$apPaterno; } 
 if( $_POST["apMaterno"] == ""){ $apMaterno= "apMaterno"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$apMaterno; } 
 if( $_POST["edad"] == ""){ $edad= "Edad"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$edad; } 
 if( $_POST["genero"] == ""){ $genero= "Genero"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$genero; } 
 if( $_POST["fechaNac"] == ""){ $fechaNac= "Fecha Nacacimiento"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$fechaNac; } 
 if( $_POST["servicio"] == ""){ $servicio= "Servicio"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$servicio; } 
 if( $_POST["dxIngreso"] == ""){ $dxIngreso= "dxIngreso"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$dxIngreso; } 
 if( $_POST["Fingreso"] == ""){ $Fingreso= "Fecha de Ingreso"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$Fingreso; } 
 if( $_POST["conIngProt"] == ""){ $conIngProt= "Condición al Ingreso"; $mensaje = $mensaje.'\n'.$conIngProt; } 



      echo'<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Los siguientes datos son necesarios:\n'.$mensaje.'");
    </script>';   

    }

    }
?>
```

> Agradeceria infinitamente si me pueden apoyar solucionando mi problema sin tener que agregar la linea de codigo `value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){ echo $_POST['nombre'];} ?>"` ya que son muchos campos y no en todos me funciona como por ejemplo cuando son selectores con muchas opciones, he investigado mucho y realizado los ejemplos pero no me funcionan como lo nesecito.De antemano Gracias!

Comment: Por qué solo usar PHP ?? Y si invitas a Java Script al juego ?? Te recomiendo realizar peticiones asíncronas esto hará que cuando valides tu formulario no se recargue la pagina, te recomiendo que busques sobre como funciona **fetch** te sorprenderá lo fácil que es realizar peticiones asíncronas con **fetch** te dejo un enlace para que veas un ejemplo de como funciona fetch: https://youtu.be/kJVPN8Fcqu8

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu comentario ya revise y efectivamente me funciono muy bien pero al guardar los datos se queda en la misma pagina y quiero me redireccione a otra, nose donde poner el header, buscare info pero igual si me pudieses orientar te lo agradesco.

Comment: una vez que guardes los datos te recomiendo redirigir con **window.location en java script** te dejo un enlace para que investigues mas al respecto: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo crear arreglos para cada *select* del formulario, que te va a permitir llenar las opciones y, además, realizar validaciones al procesar.

Antes de crear (o procesar) el formulario, inicializa variables para cada campo, de cualquier forma, vas a necesitarlas al procesar, pero también puedes usarlas para llenar los valores.

```
<?php
// Definir arreglos para crear y validar selects
$tipos = [
    '' => 'Elige una opción',
    'Ingreso' => 'Ingreso',
    'Reingreso' => 'Reingreso',
    'Defunción en domicilio' => 'Defunción en domicilio',
    'Defunción en otro estado' => 'Defunción en otro estado'
];
$instituciones = [
    '' => 'Selecciona la institución',
    'IMS' => 'IMSS',
    'IMO' => 'IMSS-BIENESTAR',
    'IST' => 'ISSSTE',
    'CIJ' => 'Centro de Ingegración Juvenil',
];


// Inicializar todas las variables con asignación ternaria
$tipoAtn = (isset($_POST['tipoAtn'])) ? $_POST['tipoAtn'] : '';
$idInst = (isset($_POST['idInst'])) ? $_POST['idInst'] : '';
$nombre = (isset($_POST['nombre'])) ? $_POST['nombre'] : '';
$apPaterno = (isset($_POST['apPaterno'])) ? $_POST['apPaterno'] : '';
$apMaterno = (isset($_POST['apMaterno'])) ? $_POST['apMaterno'] : '';
$estadoR = (isset($_POST['estadoR'])) ? $_POST['estadoR'] : '';

// Incluir solo si se está procesando el formulario
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    include 'controlador.php';
}

?>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" style="background:#2E59D9 !important; color: #ffffff !important;">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="background:#2E59D9 !important; color: #ffffff !important;">
DATOS DEL PACIENTE
</button>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="insertPaciente" id="insertPaciente">
          <div class="row  card-body" style="background:#2E59D9 !important; color: #ffffff !important;">

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label>Elije el tipo de registro</label></br>
              <select class="form-control texto" name="tipoAtn" id="tipoAtn" value="" onchange="tipoAtnOnchange(this);">
```

Llenar las opciones de un select es bastante sencillo, recorriendo el arreglo creado previamente y analizando en cada iteración si el valor (obtenido por POST o asignado por defecto) es igual a la opción a mostrar para seleccionarlo

```
<?php
// Llenar opciones de tipo de atención
forreach($tipos as $value => $text) {
    // El valor es igual al que tiene la variable? seleccionar opción
    $selected = ($value == $tipoAtn) ? ' selected' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$value\"$selected>$text</option>";
}
?>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="defoe" style="display:none">
              <label>Unidad de atención:</label></br>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="idUnidadOTRO" id="idUnidadOTRO" value="">
            </div>

            <?php if ( $_SESSION['permiso']== 2 || $_SESSION['permiso']== 1) {?>
            <div class="form-group row col-md-6" id="defoeN" style="display:none">
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label>Institución:</label><br/>
                <select class="form-control texto" name="idInst" id="idInst">
<?php
// Llenar opciones de instituciones
forreach($instituciones as $value => $text) {
    $selected = ($value == $idInst) ? ' selected' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$value\"$selected>$text</option>";
}
?>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                <label>Unidad de atención:</label></br>
                <select class="form-control texto" name="idUnidad" id="idUnidad">
                  <option hidden selected value="">Selecciona la unidad</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php //}else{?>
            <?php } ?>
```

Para los campos de texto es mucho más sencillo, solo haces `echo` de la variable correspondiente:

```
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Nombre:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" placeholder="Escribe el Nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="apellidos">Apellido paterno:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="apPaterno" id="apPaterno" value="<?php echo $apPaterno ?>" placeholder="Escribe el apellido paterno">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="apellidos">Apellido materno:</label>
              <input class="form-control texto" type="text" name="apMaterno" id="apMaterno" value="<?php echo $apMaterno ?>" placeholder="Escribe el apellido materno">
            </div>

            <!-- quité algunos campos -->

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="nombres">Estado de residencia:</label>
              <option hidden selected value="">Selecciona el estado</option>
              <select class="form-control texto" name="estadoR" id="estadoR">
                <option selected hidden disabled value="">Selecciona el estado</option>
```

Llenar las opciones para estado es igual que las anteriores, solo hay que encerrar entre llaves los elementos de arreglos para evitar errores:

```
<?php
foreach ($estado as $row) {
    $selected = ($row['idEstado'] == $estadoR) ? ' selected' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"{$row['idEstado']}\"$selected>{$row['estado']}</option>";
};
?>
              </select>
            </div>

            <!-- quité más campos -->

                  <div class="modal-footer">

                    <input type="hidden" name="guardarPaciente" value="si" />
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrar" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```

### Procesar formulario

Ya tienes definidas todas las variables necesarias para validar y generar mensajes de error o guardar

```
<?php
// Primero se realizan las validaciones
$mensaje = '';
if($tipoAtn == '' || !isset($tipos[$tipoAtn]) {
    $mensaje .= 'Selecciona el tipo de atención\n';
}
if($nombre == '') {
    $mensaje .= 'El nombre no pude quedar vacío\n';
}
// Continúa validando todos los datos, concatenando los errores a $mensaje

// Al final, verificas qué contiene mensaje para saber qué hacer
if($mensaje == '') {
    // Todo salió bien, puedes guardar y finalizar o redirigir
} else {
    // Hubo errores, hay que mostrar el mensaje
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Corrige los siguientes errores:\n<?php echo $mensaje; ?>");
    </script>
<?php

}
```